# jonkykong/SideMenu Change background color text color when selected

Tags: swift

I am using the nice sidemenu from jonkykong/SideMenu.

https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#sidemenumanager

Everything is fine but I can not figure out how to change the tableview color when I select it?  It is always gray.

I have tried to add things like didUnhighlightRowAt but that does not work.

Anyone have the simple solution?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show some of the code, the implementation, so we can attempt to figure out where the issue is happening?  Without more context, there is little that we can do.

Comment: same as the code in the link above...

Comment: why you not use StoryBoard ViewController and put tableView on it?